# Sampling harmonic oscillator eigenfunctions

Tags: statistics, quantum-mechanics

What is the most computationally efficient way of sampling $x$ from the distribution
$|\psi_n(x)|^2$ for a given $n$, where $\psi_n(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n
n!}}\pi^{-1/4}\exp(-x^2/2)H_n(x)$ is a quantum harmonic oscillator
eigenfunction and $H_n(x)$ is a physicist's Hermite polynomial?

The rejection method could be used, but care would be needed because
$|\psi_n(x)|^2$ diverges at the classical turning points at large $n$,
so that the proposal distribution would need appropriate peaks.  The Metropolis algorithm should work, but
may not be the most efficient solution given the need fully to
decorrelate successive samples.